# How to pass urls from CSV list into a python GET request

Tags: csv, get, python-requests

I have a CSV file, which contains a list of Google extension IDs.
I'm writing a code that will read the extension IDs, add the webstore url, then perform a basic get request:

```
import csv
import requests

with open('small.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        urls = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/" + row[0]
        print urls
        r = requests.get([urls])
```

Running this code results in the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tom\Dropbox\Python\panya\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    r = requests.get([urls])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 567, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 641, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo']'
```

How can revise the code, so that it would accept the urls in the list, and make the GET request?

Answer (score 2):

requests.get expects a string, but you're creating and passing a list `[urls]`

```
r = requests.get([urls])
```

Change it to just

```
r = requests.get(urls)
```

and it should work.